# Links in toggle list not clickable because of js

Tags: jquery, css, list, hyperlink, toggle

I know it's the javascript causing the issue, but how I have no idea.  When I rollover the link it shows as if it's clickable but won't click through.  I'm not using any z-index in my css either.  And I tried to set that but it didn't make a difference. Is there something in this js that's a possible cause?

```
$(function(){
$('li.an_item').css('pointer','default').css('list-style-image','none');
$('li.an_item:has(ul)').click(function(event){
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).css('list-style-image',
                (!$(this).children().is(':hidden')) ? 'url(/wp-content/themes/theme/images/arrow_sideways.png)' : 'url(/wp-content/themes/theme/images/arrow_down.png)');
            $(this).children().toggle('slow');
        }
        return false;
    })
    .css({cursor:'pointer', 'list-style-image':'url(/wp-content/themes/theme/images/arrow_sideways.png)'})
    .children().hide();
$('li:not(:has(ul))').css({cursor:'default', 'list-style-image':'none'});
});
```

Comment: Get rid of `return false;` and it should work.

Comment: But if he's clicking a link *inside* the li, then the `if(this == event.target)` would fail because event.target would be the anchor tag.

Comment: @Blender it worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `return false;`.

`return false;` is equivalent to:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

`preventDefault` stops your link from acting like a link, which is why it doesn't work.